Is the Hammer Grammar out of date?
"German grammar and usage" by A.E.Hammer (1971!) used to be THE authority for English-speaking German students. His old-fashioned focus on separable v. inseparable prefixes perhaps lead him to overlook the fact that his statement: 'a separable prefix precedes the ge- of the past part., and is written as one word' applies to all Partikelverben, with or without a 'ge' in the past participle (aus-probiert, an-vertraut, nach-vollzogen etc); but is the general principle no longer accepted, for reasons of which I am unaware?

The reason why anvertrauen and nachvollziehen have no -ge- in their past participle is that they have two prefixes, one being separable and one being inseparable. In the case of ausprobieren, the pro- is not a prefix in a strict sense because the is no verb bieren but grammarwise it behaves as if pro- was a inseparable prefix.

I don't understand the question. Maybe it would help if you explained more clearly what you think contradicts the rule or what you think would be a better formulation.

All verbs with the suffix -ieren lack a 'ge' in the past participle, hence aus-probiert.

The rule in Hammer is that you add the separable prefix to the normal past participle of the basic verb.

The rule is fine, but official sites such as DfdS and most on the internet rely on the idea that the ge is placed between the particle and "the verb", which simply does not work for most strong verbs

Sorry David, but this rule does not work unless the PP has the same vowel as the infinitive.

You understand this statement the wrong way. It's true for all prefixed verbs, yes. But that's not the point. The statement compares e.g.

kaufen — gekauft
einkaufen — eingekauft
verkaufen — verkauft

It is not easily clear why ein- and ver- behave differently. Of course, if you introduce an additional separable prefix as e.g. in

ausverkaufen — ausverkauft

it's clear that this works for all verbs, not only for those with a ge.

There is by the way a very old linguistic reason for this which is about that ge prefix. Old and Middle and even early New High German had no Partizip II but instead imperfective/perfective verbs, same as e.g. Russian still has today. That ge was the prefix used for the perfective verb that belonged to an imperfective verb.
But this was only the general rule.
There were more perfective verbs with their very own prefixes. That's the verbs that have inseparable prefixes nowadays. They don't need the ge to mark the perfective aspect because they were perfective to begin with.

Any source for the part about perfective and imperfective verbs? It seems plain wrong to me. Actually Old High German had a perfect participle with a gi- prefix. For example, the forms of ritan (to ride, modern German reiten) are rītan – rītu – reit – ritun – giritan. This prefix later became ge-. See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Althochdeutsche_Sprache#Verben

I see prefixed verbs as having a real fixed prefix, as against "Partikelverben" which have an independent "Partikel", written together with past participle or verb in a subordinate clause. Bernard

@RHa: the prefix "ge-" is now lexicalised but once was productive. It is not only left as the indication of the PPP but also in "Gebrüder" and similar words. You have that also in Gothic ("-ga"). An even more striking example would be Walter von der Vogelweides use of "ich saz" for "I sat" (imperfective) vs. "ich gesaz*" for "I sat down" (perfective).
